# Address to coordinate in objective c in google map

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I have 60 address and I want to add the pin for every address. I want to use google maps and not Apple maps. I have a loop outside, and calling this method for 100 elements.

And some times I got this error:   `*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array`
And the error is not regular, I mean the error does not corresponds to an exact address. Sometimes I got 20 errors, sometimes 15,...

Does anyone know how to resolve it?
thank you

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D) getLocationFromAddress:(NSString*) address
{  
    NSError *error = nil;


    NSString *lookUpString;
    NSDictionary *jsonDict;
    NSData *jsonResponse;
    NSArray *locationArray;

lookUpString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@&sensor=true", address];

    lookUpString = [lookUpString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];

    jsonResponse = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:lookUpString]];

    jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonResponse options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    locationArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    locationArray = [[[jsonDict valueForKey:@"results"] valueForKey:@"geometry"] valueForKey:@"location"];

    @try {
        locationArray = [locationArray objectAtIndex:0];
         NSLog(@" LOADING, %d, %d, %d", [locationArray count], [jsonDict count], [jsonResponse length]);
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR LOADING, %d, %d, %d", [locationArray count], [jsonDict count], [jsonResponse length]);

    }
    @finally {

    }

    NSString *latitudeString = [[NSString alloc] init];
    latitudeString = [locationArray valueForKey:@"lat"];

    NSString *longitudeString = [[NSString alloc] init];
    longitudeString = [locationArray valueForKey:@"lng"];


    NSString *statusString = [[NSString alloc] init];
    statusString = [jsonDict valueForKey:@"status"];


    double latitude = 0.0;
    double longitude = 0.0;

    if ([statusString isEqualToString:@"OK"])
    {
        latitude = [latitudeString doubleValue];
        longitude = [longitudeString doubleValue];
    }

    else
        NSLog(@"Something went wrong, couldn't find address");


    _location.longitude = longitude;
    _location.latitude = latitude;

    return _location;

}
```

Comment: You do not check the error returned from the json call. Maybe it contains helpful information?

Comment: I think the problem is loop, I have to send one after one...